# From callbacks to async/await in Hapi v17

Tags: javascript, async-await, hapi.js

I'm using **monk** to query my mongodb in a simple Hapi v17 app.

In v16 I used to retrieve all items in my db using:

```
videodb.find({}, {sort: {'created_on': -1}}, function(err, videos) {
  console.log(videos);
  return reply("ok");
});
```

In v17 this doesn't work. Hapi v17 always requires a return function to be visible and my "callback-powered" functions are being executed in last place, when the page rendering occurred.

The meaning of this is: I can't simply put the reply function inside the callback. I think I need to use promises or async/await functions. But I've been trying for hours to understand how.

Can anybody "translate" the code above into a valid Hapi v17 code that simply calls h.view("home") **after** monk has retrieved the data from the db?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monk should return a promise so you could rewrite your code into

```
const videos = await videodb.find({}, {sort: {'created_on': -1}});
...
```

Comment: Quick and life-saving answer.